# good smart home actions for dimmer switch

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I want to develop smart home actions for dimmer product,
What device traits type I need to use, I know it need
OnOff traits, but what about the power level control,
it need to set 0-100%, what trait I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

For a [light](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/light) dimmer, in addition to the [OnOff](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff) trait, it sounds like you want to implement the [Brightness](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/brightness) trait. This lets you set the power level to an integer in between 0 and 100 inclusive.